# Not able to Configure a receive location schedule in BizTalk Server

Tags: scheduled-tasks, biztalk, biztalk-2016

I am not able to schedule the BizTalk interfaces in BizTalk 2016. The Service window recurrence section which appears below service window section is not visible. How can I make it visible. I have also installed the BizTalk scheduled task adapter and also BizTalk CU8 is also installed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please install the Feature Pack 1 or newer than for BizTalk2016 then only you can get this property.

Please refer below Microsoft Doc to understand it properly,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/how-to-configure-scheduling-for-a-receive-location